# when window resize tag div cannot full window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

this is my html

```
<body>
   <div id="bg_img">
   </div>
</body>
```

this is my jquery

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var height = $(window).height();
    var width = $(window).width();
        $("#bg_img").css({
          "width": width,
          "height":height
    });
});
```

But when i resize window have a space at right and bottom window?
Please help me

Comment: Write your `#bg_img` css here.

Answer (score 0):

By default, body has a margin.  Add the following css:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Thank for help! but i has use reset.css and in it have body {margin:0}. The space only appear when i resize window

Comment: I think i had find solution. This error because i place my jquery code in $(document).ready(function)

Comment: again. Thank for hep!